# Are bond ETF capital gains taxed similar to stock or stock funds if held for more than 1 year?

Tags: united-states, taxes, etf, bonds, capital-gain

Are gains on bond ETFs held for more than one year taxed at a lower rate, similar to stocks and funds holding stocks? I'm referring to the change in price of the fund, not dividends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appreciation of a Capital Asset is a [Capital Gain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_gain).   In the United States, Capital Gains get favorable tax treatment after being held for 12 months.

From the [IRS newsroom](http://www.irs.gov/newsroom/article/0,,id=106799,00.html):

> Capital gains and losses are
>   classified as long-term or short-term,
>   depending on how long you hold the
>   property before you sell it. If you
>   hold it more than one year, your
>   capital gain or loss is long-term. If
>   you hold it one year or less, your
>   capital gain or loss is short-term.
>
> The tax rates that apply to net
>   capital gain are generally lower than
>   the tax rates that apply to other
>   income. For 2009, the maximum capital
>   gains rate for most people is15%. For
>   lower-income individuals, the rate may
>   be 0% on some or all of the net
>   capital gain. Special types of net
>   capital gain can be taxed at 25% or
>   28%.

The IRS defines a Capital Asset as "most property you own" with a list of exclusions found in [Schedule D Instructions](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040sd.pdf).  None of the exclusions listed relate to Bond ETFs.

Comment: There are exclusions, such as gold and futures contracts. They never get favorable treatment. That's what made me wonder about bonds ETFs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct.